# Test if a display object is on the display list or not

Tags: actionscript-3

What's a simple way to detect if a display object is currently on the display list?

Comment: do you mean within the visible bounds of the stage, or just instantiated? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(yourObject.stage)
{
   //on stage
}
```

Comment: You can also do `stage.contains(displayObject)` too.

Comment: It does'n work in a function that handles Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE and Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE event. I think it's a bug in AS3.